# Different Subdomains for Different Cities

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, subdomain

I am developing a website using Codeigniter that will have different subdomains for different US cities, like `Boston.mysite.com, NYC.mysite.com, Philadelphia.mysite.com` just like Groupon, Yelp etc. However have never done this before and do not know how to achieve this! Assume my site currently mashes all the cities together but now I want to seperate them into different cities.

**Question 1**: How do I seperate my website into different cities, each with its own subdomain?

**Question 2**: Do I have need to duplicate my controllers, views, models for the different cities? What about the database? At this point I dont think there will be any difference in the site for the different cities except the database will not be shared among the different cities

**Question 3**: Is using IP address a good way to find out which city a user is in so as to redirect the user to the different subdomains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter subdomains are just folders parallel to the www folder in the site folder.

Example: /site/boston/htdocs

They could certainly all share the same database, as the database config is in the application/config and you could have the system folder setup for shared resources across all subdomains. You will still need to setup all the subdomains vhosts in apache.

Comment: I notice u mention setting al subdomains in apache. Does this mean it cannot be done in shared hosting via cpanel? I need at least a VPS?

Comment: Usually shared hosting plans have a specific subdomain policy.  You should check with your host.

Comment: AlienWebguy: Do you know of any tutorials/webpages that describe how this can be done? I cant seem to find any...

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be helpful.  Was doing the same research and came across it.
They recommend using the HTTP_HOST element of the built-in $_SERVER array

[Same database & layout for multiple domains, but different logo on each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830686/same-database-layout-for-multiple-domains-but-different-logo-on-each)